# how to find angular tag definition in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I was wondering if there is a shortcut in vs code to find the angular tag definition(my comp. tag: `<fme-root></fme-root>` ). As you know if we mouse hover over on function definition and do the control +alt then we could switch back to the function definition. is there any way that I could do this to find the component definition in vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension provides this functionality.

[image]